# GNU ARM Eclipse 3.2.1 Empty Template HAL_Delay causes inf loop

Tags: eclipse, arm, gnu, stm32, stm32f4

I got Eclipse Neon GNU ARM Eclipse Plugin Vers. 3.2.1 and a STM32F411RE Nucleo Board. I followed this guide: http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/

I succesfully installed the Toolchain, made a Blinky programm with the template that works, I can also change said Blinky prog, with i.e the `HAL_Delay(ms)` function.

However once I create an empty project, everytime the code reaches the `HAL_Delay` function, it causes an infinite loop.

This Code works with the online compiler:

```
int main(){

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin =GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FAST;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    // Infinite loop
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_Delay(2000);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(2000);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
}
```

However in Eclipse I get a infinite loop when it reaches `HAL_Delay`.
BUT the function works in the Blinky template, the init @ SysCLK is the same for both though.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Edit: Just got the HAL_Delay to work, solution was to modify the _inithardware.c located in the source folder. line 70, 
// Disable when using RTOSes, since they have their own handler.
#if 1 <<< this was 0 before changed to 1.
 
Also I used the elseif in the SystemClock_Config, using HSI instead of HSE, I made comments around the 1st if HSE part, that way HAL_Delay() works now.

Comment: If you managed to find the solution on your own then you can go ahead and answer your own question rather than updating in a comment.

Comment: @ bence yeah it was late and I didn't see the button for that :P, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is to set the if statement in _initialize_hardware.c Line 70/71 to 1, in order for Systick_Handler() to call HAL_IncTick();